# How to make an averageif formula so that the column in the reference table could be variable

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to get average of sum rows. My problem is that my values are in some columns and I want the formula to find the column based on the value I give it, automatically.

In other words how to create an `averageif` formula so that the column in the reference table could be variable?

Comment: INDIRECT() with index() and match() is one possibility.

Comment: A non-volatile INDEX set-up should be possible.

Comment: Probably INDIRECT () is not even necessary if the column is always on the same sheet

Comment: Some sample data/attempted eqn/formula (possibly accompanied by a screenshot e.g.) would help to devise a solution tailored to your precise needs. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Screenshot refers:

```
=AVERAGEIFS(INDEX(E4:J10,0,M3),D4:D10,L5)
```

[image: Averageifs formula]